# wordpress plugin JSON API search within specific category

Tags: plugins, json, plugin-json-api

From the JSON API plugin doc

I notice that I can get the post within some category

```
http://abc.com/?json=get_category_posts&id=9
```

And I can also search the post

```
http://abc.com/?json=get_search_results&search=keywords
```

However, are there anyway to implement search within some category? Thanks

Comment: please provide a link at minimum to your post so we know which plugin you are referencing. I imagine you will also get better support for the plugin by going directly to the author first since this does not seem like a WordPress specific question.

Comment: http://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api/   , Thanks

Answer (score -1):

For finding post with specific category, Here is solution.

Use https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api/ plugin

And fire http://localhost:8080/wordpress/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?filter[category_name]=android

Change category name instead of android.

Thanks.

Comment: this doesn't actually do a search